# What would be the best raid composition/role for Titan?

Tags: vindictus

What should we run?

Which character fits best in the "harpooner" role?

What's my role as a Fiona?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with most raids in Vindictus, every character can contribute to the battle, although it it difficult for spear lanns in particular to survive without high defense values. An ideal party would probably be 2 Fiona, 4 Evie, 1 Karok, and 1 Lann. Don't worry too much about party composition  - individual skill is more important.

The class most suited for the ballistae is spear lann, as mentioned above he has difficulty surviving when engaging titan directly, but he can hop off the ballista when Titan is disabled and deal a fair amount of burst damage. Any class can use the ballista equally well as long as they are capable of aiming and coordinating with the party. When a player is using the ballista, Titan will not attack them directly unless they are the last one left alive, so survivability is not an issue. Titan's attacks will, however, still hit them if they are in range, so take care and remind your party not to lure Titan into you.

As a Fiona, your role is sustained DPS and survival, as well as assisting in breaking Titan's ankle guard with your SP skills. Try to stick close to Titan and hit him with short smash combos when possible. You can charge your SP very quickly by using heavy stander to block his various smashes. If his 3 hit combo or spear throw attack carries him past you, you can start a combo by swinging at nothing that will allow you to land a more powerful smash on him as he is turning around. As with most bosses that favor multiple smash attack combos, watch your stamina to make sure it doesn't run out and leave you exposed. As a general rule, try to keep it at least above 1/4 full. Take advantage of the times when Titan is disabled to get in longer combos or heal up. You can also heal safely when he begins a 3 hit combo or spear throw away from you.

Titan's unblockable spear attack can be dodged by rolling or sprint smashing diagonally away from him when he's holding the spears and about to throw, roughly when they're at the highest point. If you are too close to him when he begins the attack, you can either attempt to go between his legs (risky) or tap the sprint key rapidly to gain distance before dodging.

> Credibility: Level 70 Fiona on East with a solo Titan run, several duo Titan runs, and countless more regular runs. Feel free to add me to your friends list if you have further questions.
>   -RHINOmkII